# Visual Studio connect VB project to an .accde database

Tags: ms-access

I'm trying to connect to an access database .accde type from a Visual Basic project in Visual Studio. 
While I can connect from an Access application to that .accde without any problems, It seems that this kind of file is not accepted by Visual Studio.
This is a drawback, because the file must be protected by a password, and generating it as an .accde allows it.
Anyone can give any clue to solve this issue?

Comment: Welcome, to improve your experience on Stack Overflow please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) an [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and the [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) and [the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and if not already done, [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: Check here https://www.connectionstrings.com/access/ for some known issues with passwords